# Story about teens search for a cave called "Devil's pit"?

Tags: story-identification, books

A science fiction story dealing with teens searching for a cave called "Devil's pit"?

Comment: Can you specify any science fiction (or fantasy) elements in this story? Also, in roughly which year did you read it?

Comment: Note that there appear to be a number of real-world locations associated with cave systems that are called "Devil's Pit," so you probably need more detail both to establish the location and that this is a work of science fiction.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very obscure book by Lew Dietz that seems to have been published under various titles such as *Jeff White: Young Guide* or possible *Jeff White: Young Trapper*. The very brief description [on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1163366.Jeff_White_Young_Guide) says:

> Jeff White and his friend Skipper Doggett, new guides at a hunting camp, become involved in a mystery centered around a bottomless cave called Devil's Pit.

It was published in 1979 if that helps.

Googling has revealed no further information about the book. It doesn't sound as if it's science fiction or fantasy, but I thought I'd mention it in case the names ring a bell.